# Elixir - updating a nested map / JSON; no errors, but not updating

Tags: elixir

I'm working on some proprietary APIs that makes use of Elixir language. I'm very new to the latter, so please bear with me.

I'm still wrapping my head around the whole immutable concept, which makes things really hard for me.

```
defmodule Main.Game do
    def doRequest("test_loop", _args) do
        ballsJsonMap = Sys.Tuning.value("balls")
        timestep = 1;
        looper(timestep, 10, ballsJsonMap)
        %{:results => :ok}
    end

    def looper(timestep, loopsleft, ballsJsonMap) do 
        case loopsleft do
            0 ->
                :ok
            x ->
                step(timestep, ballsJsonMap)
                looper(timestep, x - 1, ballsJsonMap)
        end
    end

    def step(timestep, ballsJsonMap) do
        Enum.map(ballsJsonMap, fn({ball, prop}) -> 
           ballMap = ballsJsonMap[ball]
           newX = (ballMap["x"] * timestep) + prop["x"]
           newY = (ballMap["y"] * timestep) + prop["y"]
           newZ = (ballMap["z"] * timestep) + prop["z"]
           Sys.Log.debug("X: #{newX}, Y: #{newY}, Z: #{newZ}")
           put_in(ballsJsonMap, [ball, "x"], newX)
           put_in(ballsJsonMap, [ball, "y"], newY)
           put_in(ballsJsonMap, [ball, "z"], newZ)
       end)
       Sys.Log.debug("#{inspect ballsJsonMap}")
    end
end
```

The `Sys.Tuning.value("balls")` in the `doRequest` function is responsible for loading the data from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "cue": {"x":2.0, "y":0.0, "z": 2.0},
    "ball_1": {"x":5.0, "y":0.0, "z": 5.0},
    "ball_2": {"x":10.0, "y":0.0, "z": 5.0},
}
```

But the final output of `ballsJsonMap` is the same as it was before any functions were ran. I'm trying to do some basic ball / pool physics, and ideally, the X, Y, Z values would be modified (+= or -=) for every run of the `step` function, like so:

`step(10)`:

```
{"cue": {"x":1.8, "y":0.0, "z": 1.8}, "ball_1" : {etc, etc}, }
```

`step(9)`:

```
{"cue": {"x":1.65, "y":0.0, "z": 1.65}, "ball_1" : {etc, etc}, }
```

`step(8)`:

```
{"cue": {"x":1.55, "y":0.0, "z": 1.55}, "ball_1" : {etc, etc}, }
```

And so on, and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common mistakes made by Elixir programmers (new and experienced alike) is forgetting to re-assign a variable after modifying it. In Elixir, you can never do something like this:

```
my_list = ["b", "a", "c"]
sort(my_list)
IO.inspect(my_list) # no change!
```

You *always* have to capture the output after modification, e.g.

```
my_list = ["b", "a", "c"]
my_list = sort(my_list)
IO.inspect(my_list) # sorted!
```

It's subtle, but that one re-assignment makes a huge difference: you can never have that "spooky action at a distance" that pops up when other languages pass around references and suddenly values change because somebody did a thing somewhere else. A variable in Elixir *always* has the value it was assigned; it *never gets magically modified indirectly*.

In your case, this concept is sneaking up on you in a couple places.  First, to inspect the output of your `step/2` function, you would need to capture the result of the `Enum.map/2` operation prior to inspecting it, because `Enum.map` *returns* the modified value.  Consider:

```
def step(timestep, ballsJsonMap) do
    result = Enum.map(ballsJsonMap, fn({ball, prop}) -> ... end)
    IO.inspect(result)
    result
end
```

Remember that the implicit return means that the last thing run is what gets returned.  Instead of altering the innards of your function however, it would probably be easier to inspect the value up in your `looper` function.

```
updatedBallsJsonMap = step(timestep, ballsJsonMap)
IO.inspect(updatedBallsJsonMap)
looper(timestep, x - 1, updatedBallsJsonMap)
```

Or, even more idiomatically, write your functions so that the first argument is reserved for the variable that is being transformed. That way you can use the handy `|>` pipe, and omit the 1st argument altogether, e.g.

```
ballsJsonMap
|> step(timestep)
|> IO.inspect()  # <-- remove this line when you're ready
|> looper(timestep, x-1)
```

The above assumes that the `step` and `looper` functions have been refactored so that the `ballsJsonMap` is received as the first argument.

If you just need to update the given `ballsJsonMap`, give `Enum.reduce/3` a try:

```
balls_map = %{
      "cue" => %{"x" => 2.0, "y" => 0.0, "z" => 2.0},
      "ball_1" => %{"x" => 5.0, "y" => 0.0, "z" => 5.0},
      "ball_2" => %{"x" => 10.0, "y" => 0.0, "z" => 5.0}
    }

    a = 2

    updated_balls_map = Enum.reduce(balls_map, %{}, fn {key, %{"x" => x, "y" => y, "z" => z}}, acc ->
      Map.put(acc, key, %{"x" => x + a, "y" => y + 2, "z" => z + 2})
    end)
    
    IO.inspect(updated_balls_map)
```

Note how you can use pattern matching in the function clause to capture the existing values.

And just for a couple house-keeping pointers:

- idiomatic Elixir uses snake_case for variables
- Use `IO.inspect` or `IO.puts` or `Logger.debug` et al to view variables.

Comment: Hmmm. There might have been something wrong with my code after all. It appears that after the first step, `ballJsonMap` becomes a list of maps, instead of just a map with updated values. Might have to look into this before I can check your answer out, but thanks for the answer and the pointers.

Comment: Is the `ballsJsonMap` describe random balls? Or is it always fixed? At the end of the day, you just need to update a map, but the syntax might be easier if you were always given a fixed set of balls.  I would probably do this as a `Enum.map_reduce/3` and apply each value into a new map (aka the "accumulator").  E.g. 
```
Enum.map_reduce(ballsJsonMap, %{}, fn({ball, %{"x" => x, "y" => y, "z" => z}, acc) ->
   Map.put(acc, ball, %{"x" => x * timestamp, "y" => y * timestamp, "z" => z * timestamp})
end
```
Maybe you could update the post to make it clearer the transformation you need.

Comment: It would always be fixed, though right now I'm dealing with 4 (3 plus the cue ball), in the future it might be a fixed 16 (15 plus the cue ball). I'm trying to do pool or billiards physics, and for now I just wanna modify the x, y, z values of the balls, per "step". I've updated the question.

Comment: So for each ball, you need to update each of its properties by multiplying it by the `timestep`?

Comment: Yup, `x = x + (x * timeStep)`, or something like that; I have yet to nail down the actual formula, I'm just trying to modify and save to the json for now, and print those updates. Your initial answer was of great help in passing back the updated json, but for some reason when `IO.inspect(updatedBallsJsonMap)` is ran, it prints out an array / list of maps. When it's passed to `looper`, it fails because it's expecting a map. I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer with an example.  Previously I had said to use `Enum.map_reduce` - I mean just `Enum.reduce`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at the end of your code, when you call `inspect ballsJsonMap`, you're referring to the `ballsJsonMap` that was passed as an argument to the function.

Think of it like this:

Imagine you have some value x, and want to apply a function to it. The syntax might look like:

```
f(x) = y
```

For instance, imagine you want a function to calculate the second power of a number. Like

```
pow = fn x -> x * x end
```

Now, if you want to use it, you can:

```
x = 2
pow.(x)
# => 4
```

This means that `pow.(x)` will give you 4, as expected, but `x` is still 2. That's why immutability makes sense. Because `pow.(2)` will always be 4, but 2 will always be 2, as it should. The fact that you want to calculate `pow` for `x` doesn't mean `x` should become the result of that **unless** you want to reassign `x` to that.

When you're calling `Enum.map` on your `ballsJsonMap`, it's creating a separate thing, but since you're not assigning it to a different variable, or reassigning `ballsJsonMap` to the result of that, it gets lost when you call `Sys.Log.debug`. If you didn't have that call at the end, your function would return the result of `Enum.map`, because it was the last thing that was computed in the function.

In order to log the transformed version, like you want, you would need to store it in a different variable, or reassign `ballsJsonMap` to it before logging it:

```
ballsJsonMap = Enum.map(ballsJsonMap, fn({ball, prop}) ->
  ...
end)
Sys.Log.debug("#{inspect ballsJsonMap}")
```

Or you could simply pipe the `Enum.map` call to the functions to log:

```
Enum.map(ballsJsonMap, fn({ball, prop}) ->
  ...
end)
|> inspect()
|> Sys.Log.debug()
```

And that's just in your `step` function. You would need to check if you're doing the same thing in the rest of your code. For instance you would probably need to store the result of `step` in your `looper` function and make the recursive call to `looper` with that stored, updated version, because the way `looper`is right now, you're always calling `step` with the `ballsJsonMap` that was initially passed to `looper`, and the result of `step` isn't being used for anything